Newton-Raphson algorithm proof: derivating a matrix
A particularly useful algorithm when you want to find the zero of a function is the Newton-Raphson method.
For simplicity, we begin by examining the simplest case. Given a function and his root $x^\star$, whose value is unknown, we condider an arbitrary point $x^\mathrm{(0)}$ as a $x^\star$ approximation: once this point is fixed, we take the tangent line to the curve at the point  $x^\mathrm{(0)}$ as the derivative of the function at the point $x^\mathrm{(0)}$. Through the intersection of the tangent line with the x-axis, a point  $x^\mathrm{(1)}$ is obtained, which will represent a better approximation of the root $x^\star$.
At this point, we consider the point $x^{(1)}$ as a point and iterate the process until we obtain the best possible approximation of $x^\star$
Let $k = 0,1,2,3,4,\cdots$
Since in this process we are considering the displacement $x^\mathrm{(k+1)}$ from a fixed point $x^\mathrm{(k)}$ we can apply the Taylor series expansion stopping at the quadratic term.
$$ f(x^\mathrm{(k+1)}) = f(x^\mathrm{(k)})
                     + f'(x^\mathrm{(k)})   \left( x^\mathrm{(k+1)}-x^\mathrm{(k)} \right)
      + \dfrac{1}{2} f''(x_0)  \left( x^\mathrm{(k+1)}-x^\mathrm{(k)} \right)^2
\tag{1}
$$
Now we consider a function with $n$ variables: we define a vector $\mathbf{q}$ composed of the $n$ variables and the gradient $\mathbf{g}$ composed of the first derivatives of the function
$$
\mathbf{q} =
  \begin{vmatrix}
   q_1 \\
   q_2 \\
   \cdots \\
   q_n \\
  \end{vmatrix}
\qquad
\mathbf{g(q)} =
  \begin{vmatrix}
   \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial q_1} \\
   \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial q_2} \\
   \cdots \\
   \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial q_n} \\
  \end{vmatrix}
$$
Applying (1) in the $n$-dimensional case, we obtain
$$ f(\mathbf{q}^\mathrm{(k+1)}) = f(\mathbf{q}^\mathrm{(k)})
+ \mathbf{g}(\mathbf{q}^\mathrm{(k)})   \left( \mathbf{q}^\mathrm{(k+1)}-\mathbf{q}^\mathrm{(k)} \right)
+ \dfrac{1}{2} \mathbf{H}(\mathbf{q}^\mathrm{(k)})  \left( \mathbf{q}^\mathrm{(k+1)}-\mathbf{q}^\mathrm{(k)} \right)^2
\tag{2}
$$
with $\mathbf{H}(\mathbf{q}^\mathrm{(k)})$ the Hessian matrix.
At this point, the text asks to derive (2) with respect to the $i$-th $q^\mathrm{(k+1)}$ variable,
$$ \dfrac{\partial }{\partial q^\mathrm{(k+1)}} f(\mathbf{q}^\mathrm{(k+1)})$$
now is necessary to apply the derivative to a square matrix, in this case the Hessian. How is this operation performed? Is the derivative of each single element of the Hessian considered?

$
\def\bb{\mathbb}
\def\d{\cdot}
\def\h{\tfrac12}
\def\f{f_+}
\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\p{\partial}
\def\H{{\large\cal H}}
\def\bR#1{\Big(#1\Big)}
\def\BR#1{\Big[#1\Big]}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\q{\quad}      \def\qq{\qquad}
\def\qif{\q\iff\q} \def\qiq{\q\implies\q}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\hess#1#2#3{\grad{^2 #1}{#2\,\p #3}}
\def\Hess#1#2{\grad{^2 #1}{#2^2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\g#1{\color{green}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\red{\LR{#1}}}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
$For typing convenience, suppress superscripts indicating the explicit iteration count.
Instead, assume unsuperscripted variables are at the $k^{th}$ iteration
while a simple + superscript denotes the ${(k+\o)}^{st}$ iteration, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
f &= f(x^{(k)}),\qq J = \grad fx,\qq \H = \grad Jx = \Hess{f}x \\
x &= x^{(k)},\qq\q dx = x^{(k+\o)} - x^{(k)} \\
\\
f^+ &= f(x^{(k+\o)})  = f + J\:dx + \h\,dx^T\H\,dx  \\
}$$
NB: $\;\H$ is a third-order tensor.
Extracting the $i^{th}$ component of each term in the last equation yields
(use subcripts to indicate components)
$$\eqalign{
f^+_i
 &= f_i \;+\; \BR{J\:dx}_i \;+\; \BR{\h\,dx^T\H\,dx}_i  \\
 &= f_i \;+\; J_i\d dx \;+\; \h\,dx^T\H_i\,dx  \\
}$$
where the vector $J_i$ and the matrix $\H_i$ are given by
$$
J_i = \grad{f_i}x,\qq\H_i = \Hess{f_i}x \qq\qq\q
$$
